# OS X brew: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

On OS X (El Capitan, but likely to be also the case for previous version os OS X) the following error can take place after upgrading OS X and removing OS X beta versions.

> Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L
>   /usr/bin/install_name_tool

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this type of issue:

Run in Terminal /usr/bin/otool and check the resulting error message.

If you get the following error message:

> xcrun: error: active developer path
>   ("/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist,
>   use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify

Then simply update the path to Xcode using xcode-select command in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

This should fix the issue and let you run all brew commands without any problem.